# Scrolling div in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular7

I am creating simple drag and drop functionality.

On dragging an element i want to scroll div by some amount to top or bottom.

I am using angular material cdk drag and drop.

Container:

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="dropElement($event)" #ordersList>
```

I am referencing the container with elements using:

```
@ViewChild('ordersList', {read: ElementRef}) ordersListRef: ElementRef;
```

How can i change position of the scroll of this element, something like this doesnt work

```
this.ordersListRef.nativeElement.scrollTop += 20;
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz for the same?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axk9wx I am even more amazed because on stackblitz its working no idea why

Comment: What is bad that when this autoscrolling is present track of element position is lost. And it is still not working in my dev env

Comment: then error must be in your local code , revise it once again. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hi be sure that you are setting the native element to the container that has scroll, I had same issue as you and notice I was using the wrong element. But that doesn't solve the issue, now it scrolls fine, but after scrolling it's not recognizing the new elements so for example if you drag and scroll down, the drop will be on the latest element you saw before the scroll.

Comment: *"that doesn't solve the issue"*: the answer section is for answers that solve the issue.